# Refresh an Angular page (controller $scope, directive $scope) to emulate a first load of a page not $window.location.reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I am looking for a method to clear or refresh my Angular app, that is not as crude as `$window.location.reload();`.

I have an issue where my Highcharts graphs (using highcharts-ng) do not render properly on back navigation (i.e. once you have loaded the page and browse a different page and go back to the first page). It is a question I have posted on Stackoverflow and on Highcharts' forum, but had no luck with a resolution.

Anyway, I have searched high and low for the best method to reload my page (it is the only working solution that renders my graphs correctly), but only found `$window.location.reload();' to work. However, this is not ideal. One can visibly see the page reloads etc.

So...I was hoping one could perhaps achieve something similar, without reloading the page. Perhaps clear the cached data, or emulate a call to the controller as a "first call" (if this makes any sense), clear any remnants in the specific controller's $scope or the highcharts-ng directive's $scope?

I have tried things chart.reflow(), recreating the graphs using my chart.config settings etc.

PS: There are too many elements to create a JsFiddle.

Thank you!

Link to my question on Highcharts: https://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/chart-changes-settings-on-back-navigation-in-angular-app-t37395/

Comment: if you're using ui-router, you can try `$state.go('charts-page', {reload: 'charts-page'})`

Answer (score 0):

If you use default `$routeProvider` you can run `$route.reload()`.
If you use $ui-router try `$state.reload()`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It almost looked like it is was working, but nope. There seems to be something that gets cleared when calling `$window.location.reload();` that is not cleared with `$route.reload()`. When I navigate in between the pages, and `$window.location.reload()` is called even once before going back to any of the previously navigated pages, the pages refresh properly and everything renders perfectly. But if that does not happen in between the navigation, same issue.

Comment: @onmyway maybe you have some logic outside of your controller? In this way you have to find workaround using services which will manage this logic.

Comment: I have a lot of logic outside of the controller, but these are managed by services/factories. So frustrating! :D lol, I will figure it out. Thanks for the help!